# eslint rules from root directory config

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'm configuring eslint and folders in my node.js project looks as follow:

```
src
  - libs
    - lib1
      - ...
    - lib2
      - ...
    - ...
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json

.eslintrc.js
.eslintignore
package.json
tsconfig.base.json
```

src/libs/package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "eslint:check": "eslint .",
    ...
}
```

src/libs/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./"
  ]
}
```

src/package.json

- contains all needed eslint packages

src/tsconfig.json

- has only compilerOptions with no 'dir' properties such as: rootDir, outDir etc.

src/.eslintrc.js

```
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      parserOptions: {
        project: './tsconfig.base.json',
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
      },
```

So, my case is: I need to run eslint that is configured in the /src dir, from the src/libs level to check all libs folders. When I do it, the errors I get look like eslint's rules cannot be read. `Definition for rule 'react/jsx-filename-extension' was not found`
 `Definition for rule 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies' was not found` etc. etc.
Worth to note that in src/libs/package we don't install any packages, because every lib is independent and has its own package.json with dependencies. Also, there're too many libs to set eslintrc for each of them separately.

I've been trying to set different paths in the configs but with no effect.
Is it possible to make it work in that way? If so, how can I update the config to have it working? I believe there might be some recursive way to run linter through children dirs, but probably it should be run from the root dir, but in my case I need to run it from lower-level folder